# Altering jQuery Rating Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

So I'm trying to alter this jQuery Bar Rating System Plugin. Here is the example of the plugin: http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/ . Mine will look like Example D. This plugin is based on user input. What I want is for the plugin to work by reading a predetermined rating and setting itself to that point and not allowing users to change the rating. My product rating is being transformed with XSL to HTML so there will be a number rating listed on the page. I want to take that number, hide the actual number, and display it instead using this rating bar system.  I'm not expecting anyone to do this for me but I don't really even know where to start in terms of altering the plugin. This will be the first plugin I have ever really customized to this extent. Any advice, tips, or ideas on how to approach this will be tremendously appreciated. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

This is the html that is generated by the XSL containing the score:

```
<div class="ratingSystem">
  <div class="classifications">
    <div class="oneClass">
       <ul>
         <li class="Product_Rating_Score_Values_Overall">
           <i class="fa fa-trophy"><!--comment--></i>
           <span class="scoreTitle scoreOverall"> Overall Score: </span>     
           <span class="score">1</span>
         </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once you follow the docs that they provide on getting the plugin working, you can maybe see about simply setting the select element to readonly or disabled and see how that interacts with their plugin. If you already have the number value like you said then you just simply set the select list's value as that number.

Comment: The plugin actually has a configuration setting to set it as readonly on initialization. It is toward the bottom of the page of the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization on the element would be something like this:

```
<select id="productRating">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

After this markup you would initialize with something like this(after your plugin's js reference)

```
$(function(){
  $('#productRating').barrating(
    initialRating: //wherever your value is coming from,
    readonly: true
  );
});
```